# QToolButton released() signal fired twice

Tags: qt

I make a color picker based on Qt 5.4.1. It works as this: when user clicked one QToolButton, it shows the QColorDialog. I use the QToolButton's 'released()' signal. Now the problem is, when I close the QColorDialog, the released() signal fired again. But when I change it to QPushButton, the problem gone.

My toolbutton has no menu with it. I wonder if QToolButton is designed as **this**, or it's just a bug? Because other reason, I can't use QPushButton. So, is there some workround to make toolbutton work?

---

**Update:**

I tried put only the code below in the released slot:

```
static int n = 0;
qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << ++n;
return;
```

the counter is increased 2 every click. So it should has nothing with the QColorDialog.

Comment: I could not reproduce this behavior. Could you edit the question and add some sample code? Which button signal are you using to open the color dialog?

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro: I use the static function QColorDialog::getColor() in the slot of the released() signal, may this cause the problem?

Comment: I tried that and it worked (with both QToolButton and QPushButton). The released() signal was called only once, displaying the color dialog. Did you try using the clicked() signal instead of the released() signal?

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro: Yes it can show the color dialog. That's one released() signal fired. But when you close the color dialog, there should be another released() signal fired again. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Yeah, I understand the problem, it just didn't happen here. Does this happen every time?

Comment: Yes, every time, in debug mode. I've not tried under release mode. I tried only this code in the released slot:  `static int n = 0;qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << ++n; return;`, the counter is increased 2 every click. So it should has nothing with the QColorDialog.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'll not be able to help you. I cannot reproduce the problem here. I hope someone can answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally find the reason. I've never noticed Qt has the ability to connect signals and slots **automatically**. That is, QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(). I accidently give my slot a name like

```
void on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>);
```

style, this is just the style what "QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName()" needed. So, Qt automatically connect the released() signal to my slot. And I manually connect them too. In Qt, connect a signal twice, it will fire twice, even the sender and receiver is the same!!!!